# What's the difference between these two statements (R / dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a question about dplyr. When given the data frame my_data

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(20160229)
my_data = data.frame(
  y=c(rnorm(1000), rnorm(1000, 0.5), rnorm(1000, 1), rnorm(1000, 1.5)),
  x=c(rep('a', 2000), rep('b', 2000)),
  m=c(rep('i', 1000), rep('j', 2000), rep('i', 1000)))
```

case 1:

```
pdat <- my_data %>%
  group_by(x, m) %>%
  do(data.frame(loc = density(.$y)$x,
                dens = density(.$y)$y))
```

and 
case 2:

```
 pdat <- my_data
pdat  <- group_by(my_data, x, m)
do(data.frame(pdat,loc=density(pdat$y)$x),dens=density(pdat$y)$y)
```

Why are these statements different? How can case 2 be changed to match case 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `do` is missing the `.data` argument. You need to either pipe it in, as in your "case 1," or provide it explicitly. Try something like:

```
do(.data = pdat, data.frame(loc = density(.$y)$x, dens = density(.$y)$y))
```

And now they match:

```
my_data %>%
group_by(x, m) %>%
do(data.frame(loc = density(.$y)$x,
            dens = density(.$y)$y)) -> a

b <- do(.data= pdat, data.frame(loc = density(.$y)$x, dens = density(.$y)$y))

identical(a,b)  # TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. When I evaluate 
    do(.data= pdat, as.data.frame(loc = density(.$y)$x, dens = 
    density(.$y)$y))
The following error is thrown
    Error in as.data.frame(, loc = density(.$y)$x, dens = density(.$y)$y) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default

when i specify x for as.data.frame
    do(.data = pdat, as.data.frame(x=pdat,loc = density(.$y)$x, dens = density(.$y)$y))
The function is evaluated, but a and b are different (a[8192 x 4], b[2048 x 4].

Whats this about?

Comment: @FinlaySmall Sorry, copy-paste backfire. Should be not `as.data.frame` but `data.frame`! Thanks.

Comment: Good 2 go, TY!!